# Persistence with embedded form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I have 2 entities `Enchere` and `Produit` with 2 respective `Form`.

In my Enchere's Form, there's :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder->add('idProduit', ProduitType::class); //Produit's Form
}
```

`idProduit` is a relation ManyToOne in `Enchere` with `Produit` :

```
/**
 * @var \LP\EnchereBundle\Entity\Produit
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LP\EnchereBundle\Entity\Produit"
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_produit", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idProduit;
```

In my Controller, I want to flush 2 objects hydrated with both forms...
How do I do that ?

Before adding my embedded form, my controller was :

```
public function addAction(Request $request){

  $enchere = new Enchere();



  $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(EnchereType::class, $enchere);

  if($request->isMethod('POST')  &&  $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {


      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist($enchere);
      // !!! Here I want to persist an Produit's object !!!
      $em->flush();

      $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'OK !');

      return $this->redirectToRoute('lp_enchere_view', array('id' => $enchere->getId()));
    }




  return $this->render('LPEnchereBundle:Advert:addEnchere.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```